# Unable to compose a Docker container with SQLite on M1 Macbook

Tags: node.js, docker, sqlite

I'm having trouble composing a docker container that contains SQLite3 as one of its services on my M1 Macbook. I have seen this problem at https://github.com/docker/getting-started/issues/222#issuecomment-978730011
and references to it at https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/ but I am not sure how to reproduce their solution for my situation.

The error I am getting is below

```
> [webpersonal.azurecr.io/jb-api:latest builder 4/6] RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile:
#23 0.349 yarn install v1.22.17
#23 0.400 [1/4] Resolving packages...
#23 0.512 [2/4] Fetching packages...
#23 250.6 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
#23 254.5 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
#23 257.5 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
#23 257.5 error /app/node_modules/sqlite3: Command failed.
#23 257.5 Exit code: 1
#23 257.5 Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
#23 257.5 Arguments: 
#23 257.5 Directory: /app/node_modules/sqlite3
#23 257.5 Output:
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp info using node@17.5.0 | linux | arm64
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64/node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-linux-arm64.tar.gz
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-linux-arm64.tar.gz
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-linux-arm64.tar.gz 
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.2 and node@17.5.0 (node-v102 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-linux-arm64.tar.gz 
#23 257.5 gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#23 257.5 gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
#23 257.5 gyp info using node@17.5.0 | linux | arm64
#23 257.5 gyp info ok 
#23 257.5 gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#23 257.5 gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
#23 257.5 gyp info using node@17.5.0 | linux | arm64
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! configure error 
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! stack     at F (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! stack     at E (/app/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! stack     at /app/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! stack     at /app/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! stack     at /app/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.76-linuxkit
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/sqlite3
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! node -v v17.5.0
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
#23 257.5 gyp ERR! not ok 
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1090:16)
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.76-linuxkit
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/app/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/sqlite3
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v17.5.0
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
#23 257.5 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
#23 257.5 Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn install --frozen-lockfile]: exit code: 1
```

The `docker-compose` file I'm using is below. I have removed the values corresponding to the various `MYSQL` keys.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./backend
    image: webpersonal.azurecr.io/jb-api:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - SERVER_PORT=8080
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - MYSQL_USER=
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=
      - RESTRICTED_LOGINS=false
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    image: webpersonal.azurecr.io/jb-frontend:latest
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    expose:
      - 8081
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - 3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - MYSQL_USER=
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=
  test:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
      context: ./backend
```

The `Dockerfile` for the backend where the error is occurring during the `docker-compose up` process is below

```
FROM node:latest as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY ["./package.json", "./yarn.lock", "/app/"]
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY "./" "/app/"
RUN yarn build

FROM node:slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder "/app/dist/" "/app/dist/"
COPY --from=builder "/app/node_modules/" "/app/node_modules/"
COPY --from=builder "/app/package.json" "/app/package.json"

EXPOSE 8080

CMD sleep 10 && node ./dist/index.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line hints that there is not python executable or it cannot be found:

```
stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

To chase down the issue, you can run the image standalone

```
$ docker run --rm -ti node:latest /bin/bash
root@a0382c43b2fd:/# which python
root@a0382c43b2fd:/# apt-get update
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [44.1 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [39.4 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main arm64 Packages [117 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 Packages [8070 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main arm64 Packages [2596 B]
Fetched 8389 kB in 1s (6142 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
root@a0382c43b2fd:/# apt-get install python -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python-is-python2' instead of 'python'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib mailcap mime-support python2 python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python2-doc python-tk python2.7-doc binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib mailcap mime-support python-is-python2 python2 python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 3981 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 libpython2.7-minimal arm64 2.7.18-8 [396 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 python2.7-minimal arm64 2.7.18-8 [1303 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 python2-minimal arm64 2.7.18-3 [34.2 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 mailcap all 3.69 [31.7 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 mime-support all 3.66 [10.9 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 libpython2.7-stdlib arm64 2.7.18-8 [1846 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 python2.7 arm64 2.7.18-8 [311 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 libpython2-stdlib arm64 2.7.18-3 [21.2 kB]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 python2 arm64 2.7.18-3 [24.5 kB]
Get:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 python-is-python2 all 2.7.18-9 [2940 B]
Fetched 3981 kB in 0s (11.6 MB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package libpython2.7-minimal:arm64.
(Reading database ... 22732 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.18-8_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-minimal:arm64 (2.7.18-8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python2.7-minimal.
Preparing to unpack .../1-python2.7-minimal_2.7.18-8_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7-minimal (2.7.18-8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python2-minimal.
Preparing to unpack .../2-python2-minimal_2.7.18-3_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking python2-minimal (2.7.18-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mailcap.
Preparing to unpack .../3-mailcap_3.69_all.deb ...
Unpacking mailcap (3.69) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mime-support.
Preparing to unpack .../4-mime-support_3.66_all.deb ...
Unpacking mime-support (3.66) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython2.7-stdlib:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.18-8_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-stdlib:arm64 (2.7.18-8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python2.7.
Preparing to unpack .../6-python2.7_2.7.18-8_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7 (2.7.18-8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython2-stdlib:arm64.
Preparing to unpack .../7-libpython2-stdlib_2.7.18-3_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2-stdlib:arm64 (2.7.18-3) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-minimal:arm64 (2.7.18-8) ...
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.18-8) ...
Linking and byte-compiling packages for runtime python2.7...
Setting up python2-minimal (2.7.18-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python2.
(Reading database ... 23502 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python2_2.7.18-3_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking python2 (2.7.18-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-is-python2.
Preparing to unpack .../python-is-python2_2.7.18-9_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-is-python2 (2.7.18-9) ...
Setting up mailcap (3.69) ...
Setting up mime-support (3.66) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-stdlib:arm64 (2.7.18-8) ...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.18-8) ...
Setting up libpython2-stdlib:arm64 (2.7.18-3) ...
Setting up python2 (2.7.18-3) ...
Setting up python-is-python2 (2.7.18-9) ...
root@a0382c43b2fd:/# which python
/usr/bin/python
```

You can now incorporate this into your dockerfile and then it looks something like

```
FROM node:latest as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY ["./package.json", "./yarn.lock", "/app/"]
RUN apt-get update &&\
  apt-get install python -y
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY "./" "/app/"
RUN yarn build

FROM node:slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder "/app/dist/" "/app/dist/"
COPY --from=builder "/app/node_modules/" "/app/node_modules/"
COPY --from=builder "/app/package.json" "/app/package.json"

EXPOSE 8080

CMD sleep 10 && node ./dist/index.js
```

Comment: thank you for replying however i followed your method but im still getting the same error. I found out if i exit from the image after installing python then enter into the image again, the changes does not persist meaning if do `which python` i dont back a path

Comment: You are using a multistep dockerfile. the python binary only gets installed to the image used in the first step, not in the second. when you enter the running image, you enter in the second image that's actually running. i added the python install in the wrong place tho. can you try again? it needs to be there before the first yarn command

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your dockerfile.
`RUN apk add --update python2 make g++`

```
FROM node:12-alpine 

RUN apk add --update python2 make g++  

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

...
```